# I was following a tutorial but come across an error with override. Can't figure out the problem. CS0115

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, photon

The code is the following. The error is error CS0115: 'LaunchManager.OnPlayerEnteredRoom(Player)': no suitable method found to override.
I'm new at coding so any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
        public override void OnPlayerEnteredRoom(Player newPlayer)
    {
        Debug.Log(newPlayer.NickName + " joined to " + PhotonNetwork.CurrentRoom.Name + " " + PhotonNetwork.CurrentRoom.PlayerCount);
    }
```

Comment: Perhaps a link to the tutorial?

Comment: @mjwills Unfortunately it's a Photon Course on Unity so I'm not sure if linking it would work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`OnPlayerEnteredRoom` is a [`virtual`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/virtual) method in [`MonoBehaviourPunCallbacks`](https://doc-api.photonengine.com/en/pun/v2/class_photon_1_1_pun_1_1_mono_behaviour_pun_callbacks.html).

If you want to use it be sure your class inherits from that type instead of  `MonoBehaviour` or `MonoBehaviourPun`.

---

Also see **[this thread](https://forum.photonengine.com/discussion/13527/onplayerenteredroom-onplayerleftroom-methods-no-suitable-method-found-to-override)**. It sounds like someone followed the same tutorial and the mistake was:

> I finally figured out the problem. I had a public class `Player` in the same namespace - so those methods were trying to use that class as their argument type, instead of photon.realtime's `Player`.

So make sure you are referencing the correct **`Player`** class if that's the case for you as well!

```
public class YourClass : MonoBehaviourPunCallbacks
{
    public override void OnPlayerEnteredRoom(Photon.Realtime.Player newPlayer)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: You sir are a lifesaver! this worked and now my code is functioning properly! Thank you so much! I can finally keep moving on the course.

Answer (score 0):

Keyword override is used in child class to override implementation of method with same name and same arguments in base class. You need to use virtual keyword with the method of base class for OnPlayerEnteredRoom to be able to override.
Example :

```
    class PlayerMovement {
        public virtual void OnPlayerEnteredRoom(Player newPlayer){
        // base class implementation 
      }
    }
    class PlayerTypeOneMovement : PlayerMovement {
       public override void OnPlayerEnteredRoom(Player newPlayer){
        // child class implementation 
      }
}
```

You need to learn polymorphism first then this concept will be clear to you.

Comment: Could you possibly show me an example? That way it may help me get a better understanding?

Comment: Hey! Osama, could you possibly look over my code? https://pastebin.com/7xPmNRJG because I still don't understand it, unfortunately. I really appreciate the help!