I get two errors in this Unity code, but I don't understand why
I get errors on 45,26 51,26. I get this error "RoomManager.OnPlayerLeftRoom(Player): no suitable method found to override". It is a room manager code to spawn and add the player to the room.
I want to try and get the code to work and stop unity from going into safe mode when I launch it.
Unity is in safe mode and I want to move on as I want to finish this project in 8 days.
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Photon.Pun;
using Photon.Realtime;

public class RoomManager : MonoBehaviourPunCallbacks
{
    public const string ROOM_NAME = "test";
    public const string SAME_ROOM_PROPERTY = "SameRoom";

    public GameObject playerPrefab;
    public Transform spawnPoint;

    void Start()
    {
        Debug.Log("Connecting to Photon...");
        PhotonNetwork.ConnectUsingSettings();
    }

    public override void OnConnectedToMaster()
    {
        Debug.Log("Connected to Photon server.");
        PhotonNetwork.JoinLobby();
    }

    public override void OnJoinedLobby()
    {
        Debug.Log("Joined Photon lobby.");
        PhotonNetwork.JoinOrCreateRoom(ROOM_NAME, roomOptions, TypedLobby.Default);
    }

    public override void OnJoinedRoom()
    {
        Debug.Log("Joined room.");

        if (PhotonNetwork.CurrentRoom.PlayerCount == 1)
        {
            SetSameRoomProperty(true);
        }

        SpawnPlayer();
    }

    public override void OnPlayerEnteredRoom(Player newPlayer)
    {
        Debug.Log("Player entered room: " + newPlayer.NickName);
        UpdateSameRoomStatus();
    }

    public override void OnPlayerLeftRoom(Player otherPlayer)
    {
        Debug.Log("Player left room: " + otherPlayer.NickName);
        UpdateSameRoomStatus();
    }

    void UpdateSameRoomStatus()
    {
        bool sameRoom = CheckSameRoomStatus();
        SetSameRoomProperty(sameRoom);
    }

    bool CheckSameRoomStatus()
    {
        foreach (Player player in PhotonNetwork.PlayerList)
        {
            if (!player.CustomProperties.ContainsKey(SAME_ROOM_PROPERTY) || !(bool)player.CustomProperties[SAME_ROOM_PROPERTY])
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    void SetSameRoomProperty(bool sameRoom)
    {
        ExitGames.Client.Photon.Hashtable playerProperties = new ExitGames.Client.Photon.Hashtable();
        playerProperties[SAME_ROOM_PROPERTY] = sameRoom;
        PhotonNetwork.LocalPlayer.SetCustomProperties(playerProperties);
    }

    void SpawnPlayer()
    {
        PhotonNetwork.Instantiate(playerPrefab.name, spawnPoint.position, Quaternion.identity);
    }
}



I'm guessing you have your own class named Player which is shadowing Photon.Realtime.Player. Does using public override void OnPlayerEnteredRoom(Photon.Realtime.Player newPlayer) and public override void OnPlayerLeftRoom(Photon.Realtime.Player otherPlayer) fix your issue? If yes, please reply and let me know so I can vote to close as a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/62586718/1092820
